# authenticating login level using sessions in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

im having a simple login page which i have created using asp.net c#. What im trying to do is retrieve the user level and assign it to a session and redirect to the appropriate page based on the level. But when i login nothing happens.. below is my code. can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
 con.Open();
        com.CommandText = "Select * from deatls Where c_id = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com.Connection = con;

        SqlDataReader sqlread = com.ExecuteReader();


        if (sqlread.Read())
        {
            Session["level"] = sqlread["level"];   
        }


        if ((int)Session["level"] == '1') 

            Response.Redirect("customer_menu.aspx");

        if ((int)Session["level"] == '2' )

            Response.Redirect("front.aspx");

        if  ((int)Session["level"] == '3')

            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");

        else  
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

        con.Close();
```

Comment: That is some really security flawed SQL code.  Please don't use that in production, it is exactly what hackers try to do [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Why not step through it with a debugger, check what the query is returning, check `Session["level"]` gets assigned etc.

Comment: @LiveEn: What will happen if sqlread.Read() returns false? You need to test that case.

Comment: BTW, LiveEn...you should really take a look at the built in security features of ASP.NET **[Walkthrough: Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(VS.98).aspx)**. You are essentially rolling your own users and roles framework here. If you want to, as a learning exercise, then so be it. But there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you are casting `Session["level"]` to an `int` and then checking for equality with a `string` (or attempting to). Secondarily you are using single quotes for the values you want to check. Does this code **compile**? Do you have **exception handling**? My guess is that it errors and does not run at all. Can you post the full code?

TheGeekYouNeed is right. You should first try removing the single quotes from the integer values you want to check.

Comment: op is checking int against a char not a string

Comment: Also, this type of user auth query is typically avoided due to the possibility of SQL injection. You should read up a bit on that.

Comment: The single quotes need removed since the value is being casted to an int.

Comment: The single quotes was the mistake,, fixed it now... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is begging for a `switch` statement, like this:

```
switch (Session["level"].ToString())
{
    case "1":
        Response.Redirect("customer_menu.aspx");
        break;
    case "2":
        Response.Redirect("front.aspx");
        break;
    case "3":
        Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
        break;
    default:
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        break;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree. I would certainly use a switch statement here.